# WPF ProgressBar showing issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a problem with displaying progress bar value. I want, that progress bar use other thread for updating his value, but it do it only after ParseTpSheet method. I hope, you will help me. Thanks.

```
namespace IntegrationPlanning.Controls
{

/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для PlaningParserControl.xaml
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public partial class PlaningParserControl : UserControl
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private readonly PlaningParserModel _parserModel = new PlaningParserModel();
    public PlaningParserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParseProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void IncProgressBar(int value)
    {
        ParseProgressBar.Value += value;
    }

    private void AddFileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = "excel files(*.xls)(*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx" };
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") || openFileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            ParseProgressBar.Value = 0;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            _parserModel.Workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add(openFileDialog.FileName);
            _parserModel.ParseTpSheet();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Файл не был выбран", "Уведомление", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        excelApplication.Quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `AddFileButton_OnClick` runs on the UI thread, any UI updates will have to wait until you return from it. You could move the `_parserModel` stuff in a task using `Task.Run`, so the UI thread is free to update the progress bar while the background worker runs.

Comment: Is your UI freezed, when UI thread executes `_parserModel.ParseTpSheet();` method?

Comment: Another example of why people should use data binding instead of manipulating UI objects directly. Bind the progress bar's value to a property containing change notification and you can update it from any thread you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Thanks to @Haukinger. The result code here:

```
namespace IntegrationPlanning.Controls
{

/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для PlaningParserControl.xaml
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public partial class PlaningParserControl : UserControl
{
    public int ParseProgressBarValue { get; set; }
    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private readonly PlaningParserModel _parserModel = new PlaningParserModel();
    public PlaningParserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParseProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;;
    }

    private void AddFileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = "excel files(*.xls)(*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx" };
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") || openFileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            ParseProgressBar.Value = 0;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _parserModel.Workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add(openFileDialog.FileName);
                _parserModel.ParseTpSheet();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Файл не был выбран", "Уведомление", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        excelApplication.Quit();
    }
}
}
```